# formatting data in shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

```
cat <file1>
name=HOST2
WWN=50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.82
WWN=50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.89
WWN=50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.8A
objectID=LU.R800.57488.43
objectID=LU.R800.57488.44
objectID=LU.R800.57489.44
name=HOST3
WWN=50.01.43.80.28.55.99.5C
WWN=50.01.43.80.28.55.99.5D
objectID=LU.R800.57488.45
objectID=LU.R800.57488.46
objectID=LU.R800.57488.47
objectID=LU.R800.5748A.47
name=HOST2
WWN=50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.87
WWN=50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.88
objectID=LU.R800.57486.41
objectID=LU.R800.57486.42
objectID=LU.R800.57486.43
```

---

I need output to be like this.

```
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.82 LU.R800.57488.43
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.82 LU.R800.57488.44
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.82 LU.R800.57489.44
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.89 LU.R800.57488.43
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.89 LU.R800.57488.44
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.89 LU.R800.57489.44
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.8A LU.R800.57488.43
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.8A LU.R800.57488.44
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.8A LU.R800.57489.44
HOST3 50.01.43.80.28.55.99.5C LU.R800.57488.45
HOST3 50.01.43.80.28.55.99.5C LU.R800.57488.46
HOST3 50.01.43.80.28.55.99.5C LU.R800.57488.47
HOST3 50.01.43.80.28.55.99.5C LU.R800.5748A.47
HOST3 50.01.43.80.28.55.99.5D LU.R800.57488.45
HOST3 50.01.43.80.28.55.99.5D LU.R800.57488.46
HOST3 50.01.43.80.28.55.99.5D LU.R800.57488.47
HOST3 50.01.43.80.28.55.99.5D LU.R800.5748A.47
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.87 LU.R800.57486.41
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.87 LU.R800.57486.42
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.87 LU.R800.57486.43
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.88 LU.R800.57486.41
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.88 LU.R800.57486.42
HOST2 50.01.43.80.29.6A.84.88 LU.R800.57486.43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` version:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function output(name,WWN,objectID) {
  for (x in WWN) {
    for (y in objectID) {
      print name, x, y;
    }
  }
}

BEGIN {
  FS = "=";
}

{
  if ($1=="name") {
    output(name,WWN,objectID);
    name = $2;
    delete WWN;
    delete objectID;
  }
  if ($1=="WWN") {WWN[$2]=$2}
  if ($1=="objectID") {objectID[$2]=$2}
}

END {output(name,WWN,objectID)}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help for awk version. it worked

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straightforward perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
#

sub printall {
    foreach my $wwn (@wwns) {
        foreach my $obj (@objects) {
            print "$name $wwn $obj\n";
        }
    }
}

if (/name=(.*)/) {
    if ($name) {
        printall;
    }
    $name = $1;
    @wwns = ();
    @objects = ();
} elsif (/WWN=(.*)/) {
    push @wwns, $1;
} elsif (/objectID=(.*)/) {
    push @objects, $1;
}

END {
    printall;
}
```

It loops over the line in a file, collecting the `WWN`s and `objectId`s. Then, each time it meets a line with `name=` or the end of file, it prints what it has collected, in the order of your example.

Comment: appreciate your help. it worked perfectly.